# Match a key-value pattern in JSON text and get the value for another key

Tags: json, bash, macos

Suppose I have a file with this JSON:

```
[
   {
      "label" : "deploy",
      "pk" : 2388175,
      "key" : "gsfd45"
   },
   {
      "label" : "jenkins",
      "key" : "eQtIAwP",
      "pk" : 2388165
   }
]
```

I want to get the value for key "pk" if it is in the hash that has label = "deploy".

How can I do this?  Do I need to write a script?

Comment: `Suppose I have a json file.` then use json tool to handle it, don't use regex

Comment: I understand the requirement, sometimes you don't have the required dependencies on the server and you need to come up with an alternate solution, if you can install `jq` there are other options but you can totally do it with gnu utilities.

Comment: Do you need all the values of `pk` or just the first one?

Comment: @Yaron : The regex will be broken for a slightest change in JSON, say an extra space or character, but jq doesn't break

Comment: @Inian sure but there are cases where you don't have access for binary installation.

Comment: text processors are always the last choice for things like json... @Yaron IMO

Comment: `jq` is one of the simplest programs to install there is. If you are working with JSON, you should make sure you have the tools to process it, not hack together a fragile solution using tools that were sufficient for unstructured text 40 years ago.

Comment: And how about a limited BSD system where you can't install binaries on?

Comment: @Yaron You discuss with the administrator the need to install a proper JSON parser.

Comment: @Inian what is your experience with production grade BSD environments?

Answer (score 4):

To parse JSON in Bash, use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)!

```
$ jq '.[] | select(.label=="deploy").pk' file
2388175
```

If you want to store `deploy` in a variable, use `--arg`. From [jq manual → Invoking jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/):

> **--arg name value**
>
> This option passes a value to the jq program as a predefined variable. If you run jq with --arg foo bar, then $foo is available in the program and has the value "bar". Note that value will be treated as a string, so --arg foo 123 will bind $foo to "123".

```
$ v="deploy"
$ jq --arg var "$v" '.[] | select(.label==$var).pk' file
2388175

$ v="blabla"
$ jq --arg var "$v" '.[] | select(.label==$var).pk' file
            # empty!

$ v="jenkins"
$ jq --arg var "$v" '.[] | select(.label==$var).pk' file
2388165
```

By pieces:

Print everything:

```
$ jq '.[]' file
{
  "key": "gsfd45",
  "pk": 2388175,
  "label": "deploy"
}
{
  "pk": 2388165,
  "key": "eQtIAwP",
  "label": "jenkins"
}
```

Print those records where `label` equals "deploy":

```
$ jq '.[] | select(.label=="deploy")' file
{
  "key": "gsfd45",
  "pk": 2388175,
  "label": "deploy"
}
```

Print just the field `pk` in such case:

```
$ jq '.[] | select(.label=="deploy").pk' file
2388175
```

Comment: I am using MAC OS, i don't have jq in my machine.

Comment: @suru1432002 as [chepner says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444832/shell-script-to-match-a-pattern-and-get-a-value-from-json#comment70096523_41444832), this shouldn't be that difficult to overcome.

Comment: Thanks i installed jq and it works fine when i manually runs it. But when i am using the same in my script i couldn't pass the value.  name=deploy  val=$(jq '.[] |select(.label==$name).pk')); echo $val

Comment: @suru1432002 you need to use `--arg`. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

If jq was not availale on your server, python should be there, right? ^_*

```
#!/bin/python
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for d in data:
        if d['label'] == 'deploy':
            print(d["pk"])
```

assume your file named as `data.json` save it as `id.py`, and run with:

```
python id.py
```

It needs `python3` installed on your system.

change the line `print (d["pk"])` into `print d["pk"]` if you only have python2 installed.

The output would be:

```
2388175
```

#### Edit

added the `if` check, didn't notice OP wanted to check the `label`.

Comment: I want to get the value when it matches to a particulat string. In this case if i have pass the label name as deploy then the output i need is only the pk value of that label and not anything else.

Comment: @suru1432002 ok, I didn't notice the condition, added an `if` check.

Comment: @fedorqui py2 doesn't have `print()` function, needs either special `import` or `print foo` statement.

Comment: @Kent yes [it does](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print), or at least it was something similar, a builtin. The thing is that Python 3 made it compulsory to provide parameters within parentheses. See [what's new in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) also.

Comment: @fedorqui that what I meant `the special import`, read the `Note:` part  below your link

Answer (score 1):

In awk. It's a bit incomplete but as you didn't have anything to show, you can work on this one:

```
$ awk -F: '$1~/"label"/{l=$2} l~/deploy/ && $1 ~ /pk/ {sub(/,/,"",$2);print $2}' file
 2388175
```

When awk meets a record with `"label"` on it, it stores the `$2`. Once the `pk` is found and flag `l` has `deploy` in it, remove comma and print.

Answer (score 0):

If the elegant solution provided by James Brown does not work (e.g. different ordering of the key/value pairs) here is something that tries to get at least the string between the braces into one record (by setting `RS`), then the string is splittet at the key value pair with key "pk" (by setting `FS`).

After that setup the pattern looks for the label/deploy key/value pair in $0 and then, only if there are two fields (e.g. the pk was present and a field split took place) the string after the comma in $2 is deleted and the value of key pk remains and is printed:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN {
    RS="[{}[\\]]"
    FS="\"pk\"[^:]*:"
    }

/"label"[^:]*:[^\"]*"deploy"/ {
        if( NF == 2 ) { 
            # "pk" is present in $0, remove everything after comma
            sub(/,.*/, "", $2)
            print $2
        }
    }
```

You use this script with awk like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`.

I have only tried it with GNU awk, but `RS` and `FS` should also work with awk, too.